# avgd not yet initialized

Tags: 15.04, antivirus

I installed AVG for linux through an .sh file and it worked perfectly fine until restart.

I try avgupdate or avgscan *dir* and it throws the error message "Error: Component connection is unavailable. avgd is not running or is not yet fully initialized."

I thought I was being stupid and typed service avgd start
but it said it didn't exist.

Simple answers please, I'm a linux noob.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

"service avgd start" should work. make sure you have privileges.

```
sudo su
service avgd start
```

if it doesn't work, download the .deb file from here http://download.avgfree.com/filedir/inst/avg85flx-r874-a3473.i386.deb
 and install it with:

```
dpkg -i avg85flx-r874-a3473.i386.deb
service avgd start
```

it should work.